# Как с помощью Java распечатать на принтере excel файл, находящийся на ПК.(в фоновом режиме в идеале)

Tags: java, excel

Как с помощью Java распечатать на принтере excel файл, находящийся на ПК.(в фоновом режиме в идеале)

Консольное приложение ,при вводе данных записывает их в excel файл с помощью Apachi POI .Но печати с ПК  этого файла в библиотеке не нашел. Подскажите как быть.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй это:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File("путь к файлу"));
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало.!